# Installing "gcc" on Mac

Tags: macos, gcc, cmake

I decided to install the "gcc" on my Mac Catalina(10.15.7), but it occurred an error when download the "cmake" . Here is the full report:
Error: cmake: Failed to download resource "cmake"
Failure while executing; `/usr/bin/env /usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Homebrew/shims/shared/curl --disable --cookie /dev/null --globoff --show-error --user-agent Homebrew/4.0.13\ \(Macintosh\;\ Intel\ Mac\ OS\ X\ 10.15.7\)\ curl/7.64.1 --header Accept-Language:\ en --retry 3 --fail --location --silent --head https://github.com/Kitware/CMake/releases/download/v3.26.3/cmake-3.26.3.tar.gz` exited with 35. Here's the output:
curl: (35) LibreSSL SSL_connect: SSL_ERROR_SYSCALL in connection to github.com:443

I tried install a cmake app on my Mac, and I followed the instruction to install the command line use, and I checked the version of cmake using terminal command. Here is the report:
cmake --version
cmake version 3.26.3
Then I tried to install "gcc" again, and the same error occurred. What can I do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error message you're seeing indicates an issue during the download process of `cmake` using `curl`, which is required to install `gcc` via Homebrew.

Try updating your Homebrew once: `brew update`

If this also doesn't work try installing with the `--verbose` flag: `brew install gcc --verbose`

You can also modify the Homebrew's curl command: `brew install gcc HOMEBREW_CURL_FLAGS="--insecure"`

however, proceed with caution while writing the curl command.